# macos - How can I view $PATH in a GUI

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

I understand I can use `echo $PATH` but I remember there used to be a way to view the path variables in a GUI, much like you you can view it on windows in environmental variables.

Every google / search I try just turns up with people saying use the terminal although I would like to know how to access that GUI page again. I know it exists, either that or I'm going crazy!

Answer (score 0):

***Original answer, to do this programatically in your own code:***

You can use [`getenv()`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/getenv.3.html) in Objective-C.

In Swift, `getenv` isn't as much fun to use.  [Try doing this instead](http://kelan.io/2015/easier-getenv-in-swift/):

```
if let path = ProcessInfo().environment["PATH"] {
    print(path)
}
```

which prints out:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

for me

If you need to ***SET*** environment variables that get picked up and used by your GUI app, that's a different question and answer, [which I've found for you here](https://superuser.com/questions/476752/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x-for-gui-applications).

***Better answer, to answer your actual question***

To display environment variables within a GUI, try building and installing this open source software:

https://github.com/hschmidt/EnvPane

this installs a system preference pane where you can view and set your environment variables.

More details [can be found here](https://diaryproducts.net/EnvPane).

Answer (score 0):

All these are for presenting on screen, no changes in that case although you can create an automator script to do that.

Display notification from `bash`:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-center-notification-from-an-applescript-or-shel

There's an option to create an Automator script and present a message on screen as a notification in a slightly different way.

Here is an example to display the output from `adb` to a notification:

https://gist.github.com/yarons/063c8a6cc2596e45083cf5dbd403ffbc